# Android Progress Dialog not showing while executing an async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am trying to show the Progress Dialog while making the API call using an  `asynctask`. The issue is that the `ProgressDialog` does not appear unless the API call is finished.

Here is the **Async Task code:**

```
public class GetAPIResponse extends AsyncTask<APIRequestModel, Void, String> {

/**
 * Global instance of the HTTP transport.
 */
private final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
Gson gson = new Gson();
public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
Context context;

private ProgressDialog mLoadingDialog;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private void showLoadingDialog(final String title, final String msg) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mLoadingDialog == null) {
                mLoadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, msg);
            }
            mLoadingDialog.setTitle(title);
            mLoadingDialog.setMessage(msg);
        }
    });
}

private void hideLoadingDialog() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() { //Make sure it happens in sequence after showLoadingDialog
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mLoadingDialog != null) {
                mLoadingDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}

public GetAPIResponse(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showLoadingDialog("", "Creating your account");      
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   hideLoadingDialog();            
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(APIRequestModel... params) {
    String result = "";
    try {

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(params[0].RequestUrl));

        request.getUrl().put("json", gson.toJson(params[0].KeyValuePair));
        result = request.execute().parseAsString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("GetAPIResponse:", e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}

public HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
        final HttpTransport transport) {
    return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
            request.setHeaders(headers);
            JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
            request.addParser(parser);
        }
    });
}
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Update and try below code in your **GetAPIResponse** class

```
private ProgressDialog pd;

public GetAPIResponse(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
}

private void showLoadingDialog(final String title, final String msg) {
    pd.setMessage(msg);
    pd.show();
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}

private void hideLoadingDialog() {
    pd.hide();
    pd.dismiss();
}
```

Call this asyncTask as below::

```
new GetAPIResponse(context).execute(apiRequestModel);
```

Hoping your other codes are working properly.

Comment: Did you set ProgressDialog pd as global variable

Comment: yes.. because i need to hide in the onPostExecute method

Comment: Checkout your function showLoadingDialog and hideLoadingDialog are called in your programs by giving log inside these two functions?

Comment: Post your complete code includeing your Async task class

Comment: THis is the code from the calling activity:Context context = RegisterActivity.this;
        asyncTask = new GetAPIResponse(context);
        asyncTask.execute(apiRequestModel);

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mLoadingDialog == null) {
       mLoadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, msg);
}
mLoadingDialog.setTitle(title);
mLoadingDialog.setMessage(msg);
```

this is problem with context, you are not getting context so replace this with

```
if (mLoadingDialog == null) {
       mLoadingDialog = ProgressDialog(Activityname.this);
}
mLoadingDialog.setTitle(title);
mLoadingDialog.setMessage(msg);
mLoadingDialog.show();
```

Comment: my async task is in a different class file. So, it is not allowing me to use the activity class over there. It shows the following error: "RegisterActivity is not an enclosing class"

Answer (score 0):

An easy but maybe not optimal solution is to initiate the progress dialog in the onCreate, just before you execute the async task and remove the onPreExecute() method from the async task. Also shift the progress initializing outside the async task.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  ProgressDialog mDialog;
  ....
   protected void onCreate(){
     //Add remaining code
     if(mDialog==null){
        showLoadingDialog(//send in params);
     }
     asyncTask.execute(apiRequestModel);

   }
    public void showLoadingDialog(String title, String message){
        mDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);
        mDialog.setTitle(title);
        mDialog.setMessage(message);
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mDialog.setProgress(0);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();
    } //Close dialog box code

    public class GetAPIResponse extends AsyncTask<APIRequestModel, Void, String> {
      //Custom functions that you already have. Leave doInBackground as it is

      @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(mDialog!=null){
          mDialog.dismiss();
        }

       }

    }//Close async task
   }//Close Activity
```

I added a runnable that works for 5sec in the doInBackground() instead of the http code you have and its working fine for me. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

First refer that things , how **Asynctask** work in actual !!

Here is quick example of this,

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
       pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
       pd.setMessage("loading");
       pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // Do your request
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      if (pd != null)
      {
         pd.dismiss();
      }
    }
  }
```